# how many processes can be run parallel in background

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, background, parallel-processing

By adding a `&`, the command can be run in background,
but how many processes can actually be run in background?
i have hundreds of files to handle, want to minimized the time by separating and running them in background

i wonder if i have to check how many threads i have, however i am confused about the concept of threads..

when i `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
cpu cores   : 8
siblings    : 16
```

does it means that i have 8 cores and 16 threads,
but what does it means with

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
2063255`

What are the threads here mean? and what about the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752897/determine-number-of-idle-threads-on-remote-machines) using `top` ?

i am so confused.. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what does it means with
>
> ```
>  cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
> ```

From [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> This file specifies the system-wide limit on the number of threads (tasks) that can be created on the system.

The [task](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html) is a term used by Linux for processes/threads/etc, all the entities which are subject to task scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

Comment: With the root privileges, `killall` on the user should also be able to stop the fork bomb. People say that it also works on the Linux, though I have never seen the guarantee spelled out.

Comment: @Dummy00001 edited with max possible number given in pid_max

Comment: As a newcomer here, try to avoid posting things like fork bombs without a sufficient warning. If you had posted a way to measure the limit using the fork bomb, then it would have been a different matter. But somebody +1'ed you anyway ;)

Comment: Sure, I will take care of it.

Comment: tks, the fork bomb is cool and i +1ed, but i didnt try, dare not break the server..

Answer (score 1):

i found a complete answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136854/understanding-the-difference-between-pid-max-ulimit-u-and-thread-max)

which detailed explain `pid_max`, `threads-max`, `ulimit -u` and `limits.conf`, its clear enough for me now

tks

Answer (score 1):

On an unmodified system I have successfully run 30000 processes in parallel (s/run/crawled/).

If you change the /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max you can go even higher. But be aware that your system becomes very unstable when you approach /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max.